# stepping through anonymous function in javascript with developer tools

Tags: javascript

For example, Id like to examine the variable called 'test'.

```
(function() {
    var test = function(){alert("hello");};
    test();
})();
```

Is adding breakpoints the only way to do this, or is there some ninja-foo specific to [chrome | javascript | developer tools]?

Comment: or `console.log(test)`:)

Comment: What ninja-foo do you expect? I guess your question is not about the anonymous function `test`, but rather about the local variable `test` in an IEFE, isn't it?

Comment: alert() and console.log() both pollute the code, and I would need a lot of them for doing what Im doing here (learning by examining other peoples code). I was hoping there was some built in trick to viewing out of scope variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function() {
  var test = function(){alert("hello");};
  debugger;
  test();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
 console.error(e);

 (function() {
    var test = function(){alert("hello");};
     test();
     console.error(e);
  })();
```